# Need Paypal Credit Card in joomla for Virtue mart

Tags: joomla2.5, paypal, virtuemart, joomla3.0

Now i am using joomla 2.5 and Virtue-mart 2.0.2a Version.I want to add credit card payment method of Paypal. How i add this method on my site.I wondered many places but not getting any result.So please let me know how I add credit card payment method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked on VirtuMart's site?  Checkout out this page [here](http://docs.virtuemart.net/tutorials/28-plugins-payment-shipment-and-others/108-paypal-configuration.html), it shows how to set it up.